# Javascript setTimeout() after other setTimeout has been executed

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to execute a setTimeout only after the previous one has been executed? Sometimes `setTimeout( () => next.click(), randomeMilli());` is executed first. But I want it to be executed only when `setTimeout( () => heart.click(), randomeMilli());`executed.

Here is the Code i run.

```
let likePosts = 20;
const heart = document.querySelector('span.fr66n button.wpO6b');
const next = document.querySelector("a.coreSpriteRightPaginationArrow");

function randomeMilli() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) 
};

while(likePosts <= 20){
     setTimeout( () => heart.click(), randomeMilli());
     setTimeout( () => next.click(), randomeMilli());
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doing this in a while loop is likely a really bad idea. Using a recursive function would be more sensible. That loop will create far more timers than needed and probably give you unexpected behaviors due to extra clicks occurring

Answer (score -1):

Yes its possible.
Heres an example.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    alert("waited 10 seconds");
  },5000);
},5000);
```

Comment: You can also add async and await in your example.